# "Failed setting triangles. Some indices are referencing out of bounds vertices." when the the edge index is greater than the number of vertices

Tags: unity-game-engine, marching-cubes

I'm trying to get the the marching cubes algorithm to work in unity, but when I try to add triangles to my vertices based on a triangulation table I get the error stated in the title

If I try drawing the triangle using numbers less than the length of the vertices, it works.

```
//Store the values and corner positions of the cube
public class Cube
{

    public int[] values;
    public Vector3[] corners;

    public Cube() { 
    }
    public Cube(int[] val, Vector3[] cor)
    {
        values = val;
        corners = cor;
    }


}

//Generate the grid
        gridOfPoints = new Vector3[8];
        gridOfPoints[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        gridOfPoints[1] = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
        gridOfPoints[2] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        gridOfPoints[3] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        gridOfPoints[4] = new Vector3(0, 1, 1);
        gridOfPoints[5] = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        gridOfPoints[6] = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
        gridOfPoints[7] = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

//Add values and poistions
Cube firstCube = new Cube(new int[8] { -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, gridOfPoints);

//Populate cubes array with cubes
cubes = new Cube[] { firstCube };

List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();

List<int> triangles = new List<int>();


//Triangulation lookup table
int[,] triTable = new int[256,16]{ ... 
{5, 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
...}


int cubeIndex = 162;

//Getting the array of edges
int[] triangulation = new int[16];


        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            triangulation[i] = triTable[cubeIndex, i];
        }

//corners connected to edges lookup table
int[,] cornerPointsToEdge = new int[12, 2] { 
                                                { 0, 1 }, 
                                                { 1, 2 }, 
                                                { 2, 3 }, 
                                                { 3, 0 }, 
                                                { 4, 5 }, 
                                                { 5, 6 }, 
                                                { 6, 7 },
                                                { 7, 4 }, 
                                                { 4, 0 }, 
                                                { 5, 1 }, 
                                                { 6, 2 }, 
                                                { 7, 3 } 
                                            };
//Getting the centre point of the edge in given by the triangulation table
foreach (int edgeIndex in triangulation)
        {   

            if(edgeIndex == -1) {
                continue;
            }


            int indexA = cornerPointsToEdge[edgeIndex, 0];
            int indexB = cornerPointsToEdge[edgeIndex, 1];

            Vector3 vertexPos = (cubes[0].corners[indexA] + cubes[0].corners[indexB]) / 2;

            //Adding the centre point to the vertices
            vertices.Add(vertexPos);
            //Adding the edge to the triangles list 
            triangles.Add(edgeIndex);

        }


mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
```

This is the full error message I'm getting "Failed setting triangles. Some indices are referencing out of bounds vertices. IndexCount: 9, VertexCount: 9
UnityEngine.Mesh:set_triangles(Int32[])"

[image: An image of my corners and vertices I want to draw triangles between]

[image: An image of the way I have my edges mapped]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integers in [`Mesh.triangles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-triangles.html) are indices of [`Mesh.vertices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-triangles.html).

3 sequential indices make a triangle. so:

- Value must be in the range: [0, `Mesh.vertices.Length`)
- Length of `Mesh.triangles` must be multiple of 3.
- Front face of the triangle is defined by the order of 3 indices using [left-handed rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_left-hand_rule_for_motors)

For example you have 4 vertices:

```
mesh.vertices = new Vector3[]
{
    new Vector3(0, 0, 0), //0
    new Vector3(0, 1, 0), //1
    new Vector3(1, 0, 0), //2
    new Vector3(1, 1, 0), //3
};
```

You can generate a vertical rectangle with 2 triangles

```
mesh.triangles = new int[]
{
     0, 1, 3, //triangle 0
     0, 3, 2, //triangle 1
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I'm trying to draw a triangle with vertices on edges 11, 3, 2 what should I do?

Comment: 2 edges with a shared point can make a triangle, you should convert them into point sequence, for example edge { 7, 3 }, { 3, 0 } -> 7, 3, 0 ...

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble understanding why 11,3, 2 have four points? any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From your table, these 3 edges contain points 0, 2, 3, 7, so they are 4 points if I understand correctly.